# If...Then statement to show results in a new location

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have multiple sheets in a workbook. I am trying to total columns D-G and them apply a variable if..then statement to the results.

Using the below code provide a total but I can't figure out how to get the "if" to work right and display results.

```
Dim colm As Long, StartRow As Long
Dim EndCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
StartRow = 3
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set EndCell = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
    If EndCell.Row > StartRow Then
    EndCell.Resize(, 4).Formula = "=SUM(R" & StartRow & "C:R[-1]C)"
    End If
    If EndCell.Row >= 0 Then J3 = "6 Free Bottles"
    If EndCell.Row >= 1000 Then
    J2 = Formula = ((EndCell.Row) * (0.05))
    J3 = "5% Discount"
    ElseIf EndCell.Row >= 3000 Then
    Range(J2) = Formula = ((EndCell.Row) * (0.1))
    Range(J3) = "10% Discount"
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: There are a lot of syntax issue here.. fix that first. Eg. `J3` should be `Range("J3")` or simply `[J3]`. Also, are you assigning a value on `J2` and `J3` or a `Formula`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to change the value of a cell, you aren't able to use `J3 = "6 Free Bottles"`.  Excel thinks that `J3` is a variable.  Use `Cells(3, "J").Value = "6 Free Bottles"`.  You could also use `Range("J2").Value =`.  `Range(J2) =` tries to set the Range object equal to something, which will not do what you want.

Separate note that will cause problems: You are also missing an `End If` for one of your `If` statements.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'm still learning but thats a big help.  Thanks!  Will let you know what i get working.